# Gummosis and girdling

Tags: tree-care

Let's say there is a fruit tree (for example, a plum) that has gummosis. What is going to happen (with the respect to fungi, bacteria, surrounding environment, including roots and soil), if such tree is girdled? (The idea is to create a snag useful for wildlife)

I suppose there are different outcomes depending on the root cause of the gummosis, but is there a positive scenario among those outcomes, worth trying?

Answer (score 3):

Gummosis is a treatable disease and just letting the tree suffer seems wrong.  You can treat the disease with things similar to girding.  Untreated gummosis leads to worse issues, pests, and diseases.  See this article that can help your understanding of gummosis:
[What Is Gummosis: Tips On Gummosis Prevention And Treatment](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/fegen/what-is-gummosis.htm)

You can always make the tree habitat later, but that has it's own problems since it could become a breeding ground for pests, fungus, and diseases that will infect other fruit trees in your neighborhood.